# PDFBox and embedded font kerning issue

Tags: java, pdfbox, kerning

I am trying to render some text using PDF. The following is the pseudo code for the sample:

```
PDFont formFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, new FileInputStream(fontFile), true); 
String fontName = resources.add(formFont).getName();
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, doc.getPage(0));
stream.setFont(formFont, 12);
stream.beginText();
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(30, 600);
stream.drawString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  TA ATTWA");
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
stream.drawString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
stream.drawString("0123456789");
stream.endText();
stream.close();
doc.save("/Users/Simple.pdf");
```

The trouble is that the output file does not look right. It looks like PDFBox is not able to use the kerning information from the font. I am not sure if there is some explicit parameter I need to set to ask PDFBox to render the font correctly.

Please find a sample PDF at: https://nofile.io/f/b3D1E47zFZV/Simple.pdf

What it should look like: https://nofile.io/f/BxpVVskgszn/kerned.pdf (this was generated with word and printing as PDF).

Any advise in this respect is greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PDFBox doesn't do kerning. If you want it, you'd have to read the font kerning table yourself and position each glyph yourself. In the "kerned" file, there is this for "AWTA": [ (AW) -128 (T) 49 (A) ] TJ

Comment: By the way, your `kerned.pdf` has severe issues in its cross references and other in-file-offsets.

Comment: If you know how to work with kerning values, use the `showTextWithPositioning` method in PDFBox 2.*.